# Ionic ion-range button border

Tags: ionic-framework, border

Does someone have a clue how to remove ion-range button border?

> Lines=None

is not working.

Comment: Actually there is no border in ion-range button. Do you mean the lines in the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range) ? Those lines come from the wrapping ion-item. There you can set lines="none".

Comment: Please post complete code for your question, It will help you receive an answer.